# Are children gonna be punished?

Tags: sin, children

My question is some girls reach the age of puberty at a young age maybe like 11 or 12 what if they die upon major sins will they be punished?

Comment: AFAIK, if a girl reaches puberty at a young age, such as 11 or 12, and commits major sins, she will be held accountable for those sins. But it depends on various factors, including the individual's circumstances, intentions, and repentance.